# How to break line for mobile view in lightning web components

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

In the top I have a text i.e too long and it will not fully displayed how can I break that text?

[image]

I have attached my code also
[image]

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for code. Just copy-paste normally, it'll help us help you.

Comment: I would recommend to you to use responsive design. what you will do for different mobile sizes?